# Oracle SQL String split() Regex

Tags: sql, oracle11g

In my table Client, I have a column called "Address" with some fields like:

```
UNIT 12a Street name
```

How do I use Regex to split the stname and stnumber into 2 separated columns? There are thousand of different street names on my database. There are 3 posiblities in the strings:

1. If the string is null, both new columns are null
2. If only the street name exist (no number) then the street name will be moved to stname, and stnumber will be null.
3. If the string does have number, sometimes it is like *Unit 12a ...* and sometimes it is just *21c ...*, in this case I want to split *Unit 12a* or *21c* into stnumber column, and leave the rest to stname column.

I have already try this method:

```
select test
    --Group 1: Match everything up to the last digit, and one other character
    --Group 2: Everything after group 1
    ,regexp_replace(test, '(.*[[:digit:]].)(.*)', '\1') c1
    ,regexp_replace(test, '(.*[[:digit:]].)(.*)', '\2') c2
from
(
    select '1234john4345 this is a test.' test from dual union all
    select '1234john4345a this is a test' test from dual
);
```

It does split it almost correctly, except for the part where the string contains no number, it duplicated the record into both column.

Comment: What was happened with the block code ? u should provide more specific errors

Comment: The block code splitted the string into 2 columns c1 and c2, for example with the string '1234john4345 this is a test.' it will split that string into c1 containing "1234john4345" and c2 is " this is a test.".